# Passar aplicação J2ME para celulares motorola i465 e i418

Tags: java, mobile

Galera, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em j2me para dois celulares nextel beeem antigos, porem não consigo passar a aplicação para nenhum dos celulares.

Aparentemente possui um software para realizar esta tarefa, o iDEN Java Application Loader, mas o instalador que baixei na minha máquina, por algum motivo maluco, exibe uma tela de extração que se fecha rapidamente e nada se executa após isso. Já procurei aonde os arquivos extraídos poderiam estar e não obtive sucesso.

Também tentei baixar o arquivo de um servidor, só é mostrada uma mensagem de erro de "The requested Page can not be displayed".

Alguém poderia me ajudar de alguma forma a resolver essa grande dor de cabeça?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Fiz o download do [MyJAL](http://download.cnet.com/MyJAL-MediaPal/3000-2381_4-10359171.html) e ele já arrumou tudo o que eu precisava.